# How can I access values from a Guzzle service description when instantiating a client?

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle-service-description

I'm creating a Guzzle client using a service description. Each operation in the service description contains a URI. The REST endpoint I'm accessing requires an authorization header that is made by sticking together a public key and the uri of the endpoint and then creating an md5 from the resulting string. This is used as the authorization value.

I don't know how to get the uri value from the service description after instantiating the client.

I'm creating the Guzzle client like this:

```
class RestClient extends Client
{
  public static function factory($config = array())
  {

    // The following values are required when creating the client
    $required = array(
      'base_url',
      'public_key',
      'private_key'
    );

    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'junkrest');

    // Merge in default settings and validate the config
    $config = Collection::fromConfig($config, $required);

    // Create a new client
    $client = new self($config->get('base_url'), $config);
        // Set the service description
    $client->setDescription(ServiceDescription::factory($path . '/config/services.json'));

        $authstring = md5($public_key, 'the uri value from an operation in the services.json file');

    $client->setDefaultHeaders(array(
      'Authentication' => $authstring));

    return $client;
  }

}

The services.json file contains this:

{
    "name": "TheName",
    "apiVersion": "1",
    "baseUrl": "https://apidev.example.com",
    "description": "Custom REST API client",
    "operations": {
        "GetFranchiseList": {
            "httpMethod": "GET",
            "uri": "v1/franchise",
            "summary": "Returns an array of franchises."
        },
        "GetReviews": {
            "httpMethod": "GET",
            "uri": "v1/review",
            "summary": "Returns an array of reviews."
        }
    }
}
```

How can I access the 'uri' value in GetFranchiseList so that I can use it to create $authstring?

Answer (score 3):

The client has a service description object that contains operations. The operations contain getter methods for the various properties as well as each parameter used as input.

For example:

```
$client->getDescription()->getOperation('GetFranchiseList')->getUri();
```